# ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /data)

Tags: android, shell, windows-7, emulation, adb

I keep getting

`ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /data):`

and the command prompt when running `adb shell` tells me `error: device not found` although the emulator is open.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the emulator is running? What is the output of "adb devices"? Maybe just restarting the emulator is enough.

Comment: The emulator is open, I can see and navigate.

Comment: The emulator is not attached to adb(`List of devices attached: None`), how is that possible? (It was launched when I hit Debug in Eclipse)

Comment: Does it show up as an AVD (Android Virtual Device) in the AVD Manager?

Comment: I wonder if restarting the server helps: adb kill-server

Comment: @Maurits Rijk No it doesn't show up in Eclipse Devices tab

Comment: After I restart it shows up in Eclipse but I encounter other problems.  I posted different questions for those, please answer them.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that Android's version of `ls` doesn't support the `-l` argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you run adb from the command-line. Just do a adb kill-server and a adb start-server. After that your device(s) should be visible.

Comment: After I restart it shows up in Eclipse but I encounter other problems.  I posted different questions for those, please answer them.