# ddms exception in android

Tags: android

sometimes i am getting these exception console

```
[2010-08-26 10:50:18 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-08-26 10:50:25 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-08-26 10:50:38 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-08-26 10:50:45 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-08-26 10:50:58 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-08-26 10:51:04 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-08-26 10:51:19 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-08-26 10:51:25 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /):
```

Comment: Hehe, So? Are you trying to ask a question? If so, can you frame it that way?

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236054/adb-rejected-shell-command-ls-l-data

Still, I don't know the reason and the "close the emulator" solution sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible solutions:

1. Disconnect and reconnect your device and try again.
2. Disable and reenable Debug Mode on your device and try again.
3. adb kill-server, adb start-server and try again.
4. Restart your computer and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I get it too! Just close the emulator and re-run your application.