# ADB rejected shell command (ls -l ): closed

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am getting an error when i try to run my project

```
ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l ): closed
```

I can not understand why this happens and how it'll be solved.

This shows every time when run project.

I tried :

```
1) Close emulator and start it again.
2) Restart eclipse.
```

but this not solve my prob. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what happens is that the adb's connection with the emulator breaks or becomes faulty, so android launches a new emulator although you have already an existing emulator for the same platform running. One way you can try to correct this problem is  **Go to DDMS-->Devices Tab-->Click the option "Reset adb" (which is the last option)** . You will then see some error report in the console, but after a minute your emulator would be ready to be used . See if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: What is DDMS ?? I can't do this solution

Answer (score 2):

1.Try Cleaning all the projects ,Project--> Clean.
2. Opening the adb manually.
3.Just do a adb kill-server and a adb start-server.

Refer - [ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236054/adb-rejected-shell-command-ls-l-data)

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be with Hardware Acceleration in Emulator — switching to Software acceleration in AVD manager helps, but it become unbelievably slow. Google devs [state](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221580) that they fixed the problem, but it didn't seem to fix my Emulator crash. I posted my info in the bug report. Let's wait for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

I once experienced this, to resolve it I went to the running devices dropdown field and changed to my installed emulator. For some reason, Android studio had selected a different emulator and this is what caused the problem for me. Selecting the correct emulator resolved the issue.