# I'm getting this error when my AVD crashes? ADB rejected shell command (logcat --help): closed

Tags: java, android, adb

I'm trying to run Android Studio but whenever I attempt to run the app on an emulated device (Nexus 5 API 29) but it crashes shortly after loading it. I've attempted re-installing Android Studio completely several times, different virtual devices, restarting the ADB server, cold booting the devices, and restarting my computer (Surface Pro 7 running Windows 10). Previously it was giving me a  `ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed` error but now the only things it says in the event log are

```
12:43 AM    Gradle build finished in 9 s 28 ms

12:43 AM    Install successfully finished in 3 s 59 ms.: App restart successful without requiring a re-install.

12:43 AM    ADB rejected shell command (logcat --help): closed

12:43 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any tips or advice would be very much appreciated. If this is a simple problem I apologize, I am very new to coding.

Comment: Could you run the adb commands like `adb devices` to check out if ADB is functioning as expected?

Comment: I ran it and it gave me 
```List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device```

It's giving me the ```ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed``` message and crashes. It often says that an "Unknown Device" is running instead of the AVD I set up.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886644/adb-rejected-shell-command-ls-l-closed